# Ruby - map vs each?

Tags: ruby

I have this code of mine:

```
def yeller(array)
  a = array.each(&:upcase)
  puts a
  puts array
  return "a: " + a.join
  return "array: " + array.join
end

yeller(%w[a, b, c]) # => "a: a,b,c"
# >> a,
# >> b,
# >> c
# >> a,
# >> b,
# >> c

def yeller(array)
  a = array.map(&:upcase)
  puts a
  puts array
  return "a: " + a.join
  return "array: " + array.join
end

yeller(%w[a, b, c]) # => "a: A,B,C"
# >> A,
# >> B,
# >> C
# >> a,
# >> b,
# >> c
```

What is confusing, is that `array` disappeared. Where is it? What is the difference between `each` and `map`?

Please, someone more familiar with Ruby come and correct me: I understand `map` iterates the array and returns an array, while `each` iterates only.

Comment: "What is the difference between each and map?" - have you tried reading the documentation on the two? It clearly specifies mechanics and return values.

Comment: Yes I have read the doc. Some point is not so clear to me, nvm, I have figured out.

Comment: For the future, post the code without the IRB noise. Ideally, in a copy-pastable form. See my edit, for example.

Comment: "What is confusing, is that array disappeared." - what do you mean "disappeared"? It didn't. You see it printed.

Comment: "I have figured out" -  reading documentation is good for problem solving :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev thanks for the edit. "disappeared" array results in two `return` at last of the definition. I thought I could do that. Now I change all to `puts`.

Comment: Your "each returns nil" is wrong.

Comment: @sawa yes, that is wrong, I edit now

Comment: @FaithReaper Note that the "return" value of `each` with a block passed is rarely used in the way you do it (although there is nothing absolutely wrong about it). Usually you have some processing happening within a `.each` call. In your example you basically burn CPU cycles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The doc suggests:

> each { |item| block } → ary click to toggle source
>   each → Enumerator
>   Calls the given block once for each element in self, passing that element as a parameter.

And:

> map { |item| block } → new_ary click to toggle source map → Enumerator
>   Invokes the given block once for each element of self.
>
> Creates a new array containing the values returned by the block.
>
> See also Enumerable#collect.
>
> If no block is given, an Enumerator is returned instead.

which actually means that **`map` creates another new array while `each` simply iterates and does not touch the original array.**

An example:

```
def yeller(array)
 a = array.each(&:upcase)
 puts a
 puts array
 puts "a: " + a.join
 puts "array: " + array.join
 puts "a == array?" + (a==array).to_s
end

yeller(%w[a, b, c])

def yeller(array)
  a = array.map(&:upcase)
  puts a
  puts array
  puts "a: " + a.join
  puts "array: " + array.join
end

yeller(%w[a, b, c])
```

Result:

```
a,
b,
c
a,
b,
c
a: a,b,c
array: a,b,c
a == array?true
A,
B,
C
a,
b,
c
a: A,B,C
array: a,b,c
```

Comment: Note that also `map` does not modify the original array, but you have `map!` (with the "!" !) which will change the array, rather than just returning a new one.

Comment: Yes I meant that indeed.